# Splice method instead of replacing the Object with another (given) one - just replacing it with undefined Vue.js Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, mutation

I'm trying to change the Vuex state by splicing the state.todos array, changing the one Object in array with another One that is given in my component / through the mutations

this is my Vuex state

```
`state: {
         todos: [
          {
            title: "First Title",
            desc: [
              {
                name: "First description",
                completed: false,
                editing: false
              }
            ],
            id: 0,
            completed: false,
            show: false
          },
      {
        title: "Second Title",
        desc: [
          {
            name: "Second description",
            completed: false,
            editing: false
          },
          {
            name: "Third Description ",
            editing: false,
            completed: false
          }
        ],
        id: 1,
        completed: false,
        show: false
      }
    ]
```

this is mutation from Vuex

```
finalSaving(state, index, obj) {
  state.todos.splice(index, 1, obj);
}
```

Component:

```
 <script>
import { mapState, mapMutations } from "vuex";
import deepClone from "clone-deep-js";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      routeId: this.$route.params.id,
      editObj: { title: "", desc: [], id: null }, 
    };
  },
```

The problematic method:

```
methods: {
 ...mapMutations(["finalSaving"]),
   finalSave() {
     this.finalSaving(this.routeId, this.editObj);
   },
 },
```

etc

```
 mounted() {
    this.editObj = deepClone(this.todos[this.routeId]);
  },
 computed: {
...mapState(["todos"]),
},
```

This mutation works  just fine: (Vuex)

```
 agree(state, index) {
  state.todos.splice(index, 1);
},
```

Vue component method:

```
yes(index) {
  this.agree(index);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mapMutation` methods accept only one argument. You can use an object with multiple properties as an argument and then de-structure it in the Vuex store.

Change this

```js
methods: {
 ...mapMutations(["finalSaving"]),
   finalSave() {
     this.finalSaving(this.routeId, this.editObj);
   },
 },
```

TO

```js
methods: {
 ...mapMutations(["finalSaving"]),
   finalSave() {
     this.finalSaving({routeId: this.routeId, objectToBeEdited: this.editObj});
   },
 },
```

Then in the Vuex file

```js
finalSaving(state, payload) {
  state.todos.splice(payload.routeId, 1, payload.objectToBeEdited);
}
```